# Delete Across Tables MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to delete records in two different tables. I get the error message:

> Specify the table containing the records you want to delete.

The table `MSShipment` will be the reference source for the records I would like to delete across both tables.

```
DELETE MSShipment.BoxNumber AS MSShipment_BoxNumber, MedicalSort.BoxNumber AS MedicalSort_BoxNumber
FROM MSShipment 
INNER JOIN MedicalSort 
ON MSShipment.[BoxNumber] = MedicalSort.[BoxNumber];
```

Comment: you have to execute individual two queries to delete from two table, you cant delete data from two table using one query

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I would still need to use the MSShipment as the reference for those records that need to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider setting up referential integrity with cascade deletes between MSShipment and MedicalSort.

This way when you delete the record from MSShipment, all of the detail records in Medical Sort are deleted.

This will happen all the time throughout your application.